# Chrome Remote Debugging using WebSocket

Tags: c#, google-chrome, websocket, .net-4.5, google-chrome-devtools

I want to interact with chrome browser in my .Net application and I want to use WebSocket class (.Net 4.5) and Chrome Remote debugging protocol to achieve my task.

I'm getting an error message saying "unable to connect to server" when I try to connect to websocket.

This is my sample code. (I used `http://127.0.0.1:9220/json` to get the URI for chrome websocket and Platform is Windows 8)

```
class MyProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyProgram program = new MyProgram();
        program.ConnectToWebSocket();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public async void ConnectToWebSocket()
    {
        var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        var uri = new Uri("ws://127.0.0.1:9220/devtools/page/<GUID>");
        await ws.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

This is working fine when I use `ws://echo.websocket.org/` as URI and I want to make it working for Chrome.

Thanks.